# Non trivial references with applications on order and equivalence relations

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for references on order and equivalence relations, not just trivial ones, but something more interesting with some applications, are there something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are various applications of posets in combinatorics; you might look up Möbius inversion, for example. But to my knowledge people don't really write books about posets or about equivalence relations; rather these just appear in other books for various reasons.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm looking for something simpler to show to my students.